# Generate monthly report from the android sqlite data?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, report

I am trying to generate monthly finance report from the data stored in the `SQLiteDatabase`. The code below returns `null` date

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT id, STRFTIME('%Y-%m',_date) AS _date, SUM(amount) AS amount, _type FROM personal_finance GROUP BY _date, _type";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Finance finance = new Finance();
            finance.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            finance.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
            finance.setAmount(cursor.getInt(2));

            finances.add(finance);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

[image]

Comment: please post you stored data

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that the null issue is due to the values stored in the _date column not being one of the acceptable/recognised date formats as the query itself appears to work *(see later as to how it doesn't work as expected though)*.

For example assuming a table populated as :-

[image]

- Note the _date is ab acceptable/recognised format as per

> Time Strings A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>
> `YYYY-MM-DD`
>
> `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`
>
> `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`
>
> `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`
>
> `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM`
>
> `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`
>
> `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS`
>
> `HH:MM`
>
> `HH:MM:SS`
>
> `HH:MM:SS.SSS`
>
> `now`
>
> `DDDDDDDDDD`

[Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Then your query will result in :-

[image]

**1. As such the underlying data is resulting in the null.**

From the result you can also see that the data is not grouped, and therefore summed, by month but by date. This is because the year/month derived column has been named the same as the source column i.e. _date but it is the actual _date column that the GROUP will use.

This is a simple change, just use a different name for the derived column and then use that in the GROUP clause. e.g. :

```
SELECT id, STRFTIME('%Y-%m',_date) AS short_date, SUM(amount) AS amount FROM personal_finance GROUP BY short_date, _type
```

- **short_date** instead of _date has been used for the derived column and then that has been used for the GROUP.

This results in :-

[image]

- Note! **id** will only indicate one of the **id**'s of the set.